# How to insert CollectionType unmapped image into db in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

## How to insert CollectionType unmapped image into db in Symfony?

**This is the code**

ImageType Form:

```
->add('image', FileType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
])
```

ProjectType Form:

```
->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => ImageType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'label' => false,
    'by_reference' => false,
])
```

Controller:

```
$project->setPdf($pdf);
$images = new Images();
foreach($project->getImages() as $key => $img) {
    $imgName = $imageUpload->uploadImage($form->get('images')[$key]['cropped_file']->getData(), $img);
    $img->setImage($imgName);
    $project->addImage($img);
}
dd($project);
```

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to Insert Project OneToMany with Images into db

**What I tried:**
When I remove $project->addImage($img); dd($project) One related object Images is displayed but the image is null as it is mapped => false ,

```
        0 => App\Entity\Images {#1741
            -id: null
            -image: null
            -project: App\Entity\Project {#1108}
        }
```

but when I add  $project->addImage($img); I see 2 Image object one has image => and the other has image as show below.

```
- images: ArrayCollection {
    -elements: array:2 [
        0 => App\Entity\Images {#1741
            -id: null
            -image: null
            -project: App\Entity\Project {#1108}
        }
        1 => App\Entity\Images {#1858
            -id: null
            -image: "John-Doe-65cbcbb17a4a0.png"
            -project: App\Entity\Project {#1108}
        }
    ]
}
```

Entity:

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'project', targetEntity: Images::class, cascade : ['persist','remove'])]
private Collection $images;
```

If I remove image mapped => false then it works fine, but since I had to crop image and upload I had to do mapped=> false. I even tried filtering inside foreach loop but it didn't worked.